# Graph Coloring Real World Applications

Tags: graphs, colorings, applications

I'd like to know whether recent graph coloring algorithms that one can find nicely listed [here](http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/pub/porumbel/graphs/) have found it's place in *real world applications* or are they just simply pushing boundaries in this particular field of combinatoral optimization? 
 
I already know that graph coloring naturally arises during register allocation as part of compiler optimization as well as in bandwidth allocation and scheduling problems. I also know that coloring techniques deployed in these areas are somewhat different than those provided in link. Algorithms one can find under link are mostly based on meta-heuristics and hybridizations and I believe are not helpful in register allocation, for certain.

Comment: I recall answering a question on SO where the OP had a set of items, and for each item, a set of attribute labels (like "SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE", "RED", "GREEN", "MENS", "WOMENS").  The task was to automatically infer "meaningful groups" of attributes.  I thought that attributes that never appear together on the same item might be meaningful categories (e.g., {"SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE"} might be one group).  In a graph in which each vertex is an attribute and an edge exists between 2 attributes whenever some item has both, the colours in a colouring correspond to such plausible categories.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?